# MySQL Limit Offset Difference

Tags: mysql, select, limit

I am just trying to understand difference in MySQL's LIMIT syntax.

What is the difference between:

```
LIMIT 0, 30
```

vs.

```
LIMIT 30
```

in a select statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference.

If you leave the offset parameter, it will be `0` by default.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, however if you use a select statement you can do

```
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 5,30;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 30;
```

If you using a delete statement you cannot have an offset, only a limit so you can do

```
DELETE * FROM my_table limit 30;
```

But you can't do

```
DELETE * FROM my_table 5,30;
```